# Insert/Update DB table when making new post or update older one

Tags: save-post

I was wondering how can I insert a DB row (not related to WordPress tables) only when I update or add a new post. Right now I have this...

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'insertIntoDBatPost');
function insertIntoDBatPost()
{
  global $wpdb;
  global $post;

  $wpdb->show_errors();

  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
    return;

  $ios_version_changelog = isset($_POST['ios_version_changelog']) ?    $_POST['ios_version_changelog'] : '';
$ios_version_release_date = isset($_POST['ios_version_release_date']) ? $_POST['ios_version_release_date'] : '';
$ios_version_download_link = isset($_POST['ios_version_download_link']) ? $_POST['ios_version_download_link'] : '';
$ios_version_log = isset($_POST['ios_version_log']) ? $_POST['ios_version_log'] : '';

if($ios_version_log != '')
{
    $wpdb->insert(
        'posts_details',
        array(
            'post_id' => $post->ID,
            'post_changelog' => $ios_version_changelog,
            'post_release_date' => $ios_version_release_date,
            'post_download_link' => $ios_version_download_link,
            'post_ios_version' => $ios_version_log
        )
    );
}
}
```

and WordPress auto-saves from time to time, which inserts a lot of rows in my database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read this yet? [Creating Tables with Plugins « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins)

Comment: And this helps me how? I don`t need to create tables or a how to use $wpdb. I need to update a table ONLY when I publish or update an wordpress article.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following right at the top of your function code, it will exit the function if it's doing an auto save:

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
return;
```

You may find you also need to use the following aswell:

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
return;
```

Comment: Not really working.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? The above will kick you out of the function if wordpress press is currently autosaving

Comment: I added both codes and started a new post. After 2-3 minutes, i already had 2 entries in the db.

Comment: Updated. Please note that I used this as a new post. Maybe there is some special condition for drafts?

Comment: Place it right at the top of the script after the opening { and can you confirm you don't have any other post edit screens open in other tabs and that the new rows in the DB match the id of the post your editing on.

Comment: Same result. 2 rows inserted

Comment: Yes. New post - I write on it and when I finish it (2-5 minutes) I publish. 2 rows in total.

Comment: Thanks. I will go to sleep now and check it out tomorrow.

Comment: @IulianBozeanu and MichealJames, please avoid comment explosions or at least delete all the "noise" comments when you're done, leaving only those that help getting around using the answer. Thanks.